# How to scan a file while uploading using Kendo UI in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How can I scan (Symantec) a file for a virus while uploading, using Kendo UI Upload?

Comment: anything else you might want to share .. maybe some of the structure of the code you are currently using and the problems you are facing with that code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered on the [Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/virus-checking-on-file-upload):

> The Kendo UI Upload does not include any file scanning capabilities
>   and frankly speaking, we have no intentions with this regard for the
>   time being. You can scan files via custom implementation or a tool
>   after saving them on the server, in the same fashion as you would do
>   that with a plain  element.

You'll need to implement general server-side scanning of files, Kendo UI doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    using com.symantec.scanengine.api;
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {
            int bresult = 0;
            string sReturn = string.Empty;
            bresult = SaveFiles(files);
            if (bresult == -2)
            {
                  return Content("Corrupted");
            }
            else if (bresult == -1)
            {
                return Content("Incorrect");
            }
            else
            {    
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }


public int SaveFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {

            int bresult = 0;
            string sReturn = string.Empty;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            { 
                string sMessage = null;
                try
                { 
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        // Some browsers send file names with full path. We only care about the file name.

                        if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                        {

                            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                            string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                            bool IsValid = true;


                            if (IsValid)
                            {


                                file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                                string scanIP = string.Empty;
                                int scanPort = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scanPort"]);

                                    scanIP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scanIPFromConfig"];


                                int scanResult = ScanUploads(scanIP, scanPort, fileName, fileBytes);                                
                                if (scanResult == -1)
                                {
                                    bresult = -2;

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   //your logic to remove files

                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message.ToString());
                    obj.ExceptionLogger(ex);
                    bresult = -1;
                }

            }

            return bresult;
        }


public int ScanUploads(string ScanIP, int scanPort, string valuetoscan, byte[] fileStream)
        {
            //try
            //{
                List<ScanEngineInfo> scanEnginesForScanning = new List<ScanEngineInfo>();
                scanEnginesForScanning.Add(new ScanEngineInfo(ScanIP, scanPort));
                //ScanEngineInfo scanEnginesForScanning = new ScanEngineInfo(ScanIP, scanPort); 
                ScanRequestManager requestManagerObj = new ScanRequestManager();
                requestManagerObj.PrepareForScan(scanEnginesForScanning, 20000, 20);
                //string scanPolicy = "policy";
                string setScanPolicy = "DEFAULT";
                dynamic scPolicy = (Policy)Enum.Parse(typeof(Policy), setScanPolicy);
                StreamScanRequest testobjtoscan = requestManagerObj.CreateStreamScanRequest(scPolicy);
                // byte[] array1 = null;
                // int i = 0;
                MemoryStream iStream = new MemoryStream();
                ScanResult scanResult = default(ScanResult);
                string scanresultClean = null;
                int scanresultINFECTED = 0;
                string scanresultcount = null;
                string scanfilestatus = null;
                iStream.Write(fileStream, 0, fileStream.Length);
                testobjtoscan.Start(valuetoscan, "ScanFile");
                testobjtoscan.Send(fileStream);
                try
                {
                    scanResult = testobjtoscan.Finish(iStream);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                scanfilestatus = Convert.ToString(scanResult.fileStatus.ToString());
                scanresultcount = scanResult.threat.ToString();
                scanresultClean = scanResult.fileStatus.ToString();
                scanresultINFECTED = scanResult.totalInfection;
                if (scanfilestatus != "CLEAN")
                {
                    string errorMessage;

                    if(scanfilestatus == null)
                    {
                        errorMessage = "File Scan Status: null" + " Total Infection: " + scanResult.totalInfection + " connTriesInfo:   ";

                    }
                    else{

                        errorMessage = "File Scan Status: " + scanfilestatus + " Total Infection: " + scanResult.totalInfection + " connTriesInfo:   ";


                    }

                    foreach (var conninfo in scanResult.connTriesInfo)
                    {
                        errorMessage += " port: " + conninfo.port.ToString() + " problem encountered:" + conninfo.problemEncountered.ToString() + " scan host" + conninfo.scanHost.ToString();
                    }

                    iStream.Dispose();

                    Exception ex = new Exception("Symantec Virus Scan prevented file from being uploaded   " + errorMessage);
                    obj.ExceptionLogger(ex);

                    return -1;
                }
                else
                    return 0; 

        }


public int ScanStream(string scanServer, int scanPort, string fileName, byte[] fileStream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int iRx;
            Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            string retDesc=string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (scanPort == 0)
                    scanPort = 1344;
                System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(scanServer);
                System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, scanPort);
                soc.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
                if (soc.Connected)
                {
                    string cmd = "RESPMOD icap://" + scanServer + ":" + scanPort + "/AVSCAN ICAP/1.0\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "Host: " + scanServer + ":" + scanPort + "\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "Allow: 204\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "Encapsulated: req-hdr=0, res-hdr=84, res-body=131\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "GET http://&#8221;" + scanServer + "/" + fileName + " HTTP/1.1\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "Host: " + scanServer + "\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "\n";
                    cmd = cmd + String.Format("{0:X2}", fileStream.Length) + "\n";
                    soc.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd));
                    soc.Send(fileStream);
                    cmd = "\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "0\n";
                    cmd = cmd + "\n";
                    soc.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd));
                    while ((soc.Connected) && ((iRx = soc.Receive(buffer)) > 0))
                    {
                        char[] chars = new char[iRx];

                        System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                        int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
                        System.String szData = new System.String(chars);

                        retDesc = retDesc + szData;
                    }
                    soc.Close();
                    if (retDesc.Contains("X-Violations-Found:"))
                        return -1;
                    else
                        return 0;
                }
                else
                    return -1;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (soc != null)
                    soc.Close();
                retDesc = e.Message;
                obj.ExceptionLogger(e);
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: are these samples you provided for scanning file upload streams via Symantec? Are there .NET online tutorials/samples/guides as to how to do this as we are also in the process of having to scan files before being uploaded to a server.